# For loop returning 'None'

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, edx

So I'm doing a tutorial on Python in edX. I'm stuck because I cannot get rid of the "NONE" result. Can someone tell me why this is happening and how to avoid it? Thanks.

```
def steps(aNum):
    count = 1
    tabs = "    "
    for x in range(1, aNum + 1):
        strNum = str(x) * 4
        numTabs = tabs * count
        count += 1
        result = numTabs + strNum
        print(result)
```

Result:

```
    1111
        2222
None
```

Result I want is:

```
    1111
        2222
```

Answer (score 2):

You must be printing the function return (which doesn't exist) with

```
print(steps(2))
```

Instead, just use

```
steps(2)
```

Also, you have unnecessary complexity with the count variable since you already have x providing the same sequence of values in the loop. This is simpler.

```
def steps(aNum):
    tabs = "    "
    for x in range(1, aNum + 1):
        strNum = str(x) * 4
        numTabs = tabs * x
        result = numTabs + strNum
        print(result)
```

Comment: @lloydyu24 Don't forget to accept the answer if it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting None value because you are not returning anything in function. When you don't return anything function returns None value so None will be printed when you invoke your function. To avoid is you can use return or yield statement or I deduce you are using your function as:

```
var = steps(aNum)  # this will assign None value to var but before assigning None value it has already print your desire values as result
print(var)  # when None is assigned to var it will be printed in output.
```

instead of this use below code:

```
steps(aNum)  # just print statement within function
```

Note : in above line `steps(aNum)` is not assigned so it will only print statement within function.

Comment: This just prints the `None` all the same, since the function evaluates to `None`. Get rid of the `print` and just call the function with `steps(aNum)`.